# JSON won't render properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i'm very new to jQuery :

I'm trying to render my JSON from a jQuery.ajax() :

```
$.each(data, function(key, val){
  $(key + val).insertAfter("#some-div");
});
```

but all i get is :

```
1[object Object]
0[object Object]
```

Firebug says :

```
[{"slug": ["This field is required"], "title": ["This field is required."]}, {"slug": ["This field is required"], "title": ["This field is required"]}]
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting [object Object] because what's in "data" is in fact JSON and not HTML.

From the Firebug output, it looks like the JSON contains a list or error messages. For some reason, the error message is wrapped in square brackets ([]) which turns in into an array.

What you should be doing is something like this:

```
$.each(data, function(index, value)
{
  $('<li />').text(value.slug[0] + ' ' + value.title[0]).insertAfter('#some-div');
});
```

Have a look at [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [JSON](http://www.json.org/) for information on jQuery's .each function and the JSON format respectively.

Comment: Many thanks, that was not exactly what i needed but i finally find the right solution that i was exactly looking for because of your answer. Thank you again! The missing stuff was that thing about INDEX `$.each(data, function(index, value) {
        
          $.each(this, function(key, val) {
            $('<p class="error">' + val + '</p>').insertAfter(#some-div);
          });
          
        });`